# Images of mathematical notation in newsletters

Tags: feature-request

Could mathematical notation used in question titles and bodies be rendered as images in the weekly email newsletters for the relevant StackExchanges?

Currently, one only sees the LaTeX markup, which is a little annoying.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Tangentially relevant: [GmailTeX](http://alexeev.org/gmailtex.html).

Comment: Is there a way to bring this to the attention of someone who could make it happen?

Comment: You already did, by posting here on Meta. Out of [17K+ feature requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) only a small percentage get implemented.  Some of those get implemented 1-2 years after being posted. Your was made three days ago... By the way, this is a somewhat nontrivial request: MathJax does not provide image output directly, and other TeX renderers do not interpret markup in the same way.